# Streaming video from asp.net core web API to Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, streaming

I'm facing an issue in my current Web API project. I have a database and one of the tables has a column of type `varbinary`. I would like to build an action method where I retrieve the data from that column and prepare it so when I call this action method, I can view the actual video from Android and iOS devices.

I managed to get it work on Android but not iOS, and my attempt for the Android is like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
   var bytes = //getting the data form the database;
   var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
   return File(stream, "video/mp4");
}
```

I found answers and blog posts where they used `PushStreamContent` class and I think this class is not available in asp.net core.

Answer (score 0):

Damn i'm trying to do the same but i'm having a lot of trubles.
first of all you'll need to support partial content.
asp.net core MVC updated to version 2.1.x (maybe also 2.0.x) have a new `File` method overload that return a `FileStreamResult`.

```
FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, String contentType, String fileDownloadName, Boolean enableRangeProcessing);
```

<strike>This should be your starting point.
After this i wasn't still able to play videos on my iOS i've noticed that in the response  header `content-disposition: attachment; ...` i'm investigating if removing the attachment token or sobstituting it with inline could do the trick</strike>

That's it! you just need that.

In my case it was HyperV external virtual switch that for some reason was limiting the connection speed to 20KiB/s and the videos where unable to play.

Comment: yep that was all i needed, also deleting my hyper-v virtual switches helped reaching the needed speed to stream some video, but that was because of some bug of my network card drivers